# Python config file calling custom function

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and not sure on the best solution here.

I have a general script when generates some calendar pdf output.  I configure it with a small `gen_config.py` file that is `import`-ed at the top of my main script.  The config is mostly just `name=value` pairs.

Now I need to include some slightly more complicated data in my configuration - a list of holidays to show on the calendar.  I have a handy function to add holidays to a dictionary in my main script - `add_holiday(2019, 1, 1, "New Year's Day")`.  But I don't know of the best way to call this from my config script?  Including the main script from the config is a circular dependency... is there a good way to solve this?

I've considered switching the config to json or something like that, and I'm open to that solution.  Just looking for whatever will be fastest/easiest, and json feels like it might be overkill.

Comment: Move `add_holiday()` to a separate file, so that both the main script and the config file can import it?

Comment: add_holiday() uses a global variable, but I guess it can just live in a separate script as well... I'll try that out, if you want to submit it as an answer happy to vote it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this doesn't linger... I followed @jasonharper's advice and moved the function (and global variable) to a separate file which gets included from both places.  It is working well!